# Check if return value from stored procedure is null in C# using Microsoft Enterprise Library

Tags: c#

I am using Microsoft Enterprise Library for database access and connection. I have a method that is executing a stored procedure that is returning a record.

My problem is when I wanted to check the result that is coming back from `ExecuteReader`, even if the stored procedure does not return anything the `result.FieldCount` is not 0 so it passes the

```
if (result.FieldCount == 0)
```

check and goes to else and try to read the empty data and goes to exception.

How I can check if the result has value?

This is my method:

```
    public Model.Customer GetRegisteredCustomerUsernameandPass(int Customer_ID)
    {
        Model.Customer model = null;

        string myConnection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionName].ToString();
        SqlDatabase db = new SqlDatabase(myConnection);

        using (DbCommand command = db.GetStoredProcCommand("Get_CustomerByCustomerID"))
        {
            db.AddInParameter(command, "Customer_ID", DbType.Int32, Customer_ID);

            var result = db.ExecuteReader(command);

            try
            {
                if (result.FieldCount == 0)
                    model = null;
                else
                {
                    result.Read();

                    model = new Model.Customer()
                    {
                        Username = result.GetString(0),
                        Password = result.GetString(1)
                    };
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

            return model;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the result of `FieldCount`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of [`FieldCount`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.fieldcount(v=vs.110).aspx) (emphasis mine):

> Executing a query that, by its nature, does not return rows (such as a DELETE query), sets FieldCount to 0. **However. this should not be confused with a query that returns 0 rows (such as SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1 = 2) in which case FieldCount returns the number of columns in the table**

Instead, the `Read` method on the `Reader` advances the reader to the next record and returns a boolean denoting whether or not there are more rows. You can check this for false:

```
if (result.Read())
{
    model = new Model.Customer()
    {
        Username = result.GetString(0),
        Password = result.GetString(1)
    };
}
```

This is often used in a `while` loop when multiple rows are expected back:

```
while (result.Read())
{
    //do something with the current row
}
```

Alternatively you can use the [`HasRows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.hasrows(v=vs.110).aspx) property which:

> Gets a value that indicates whether the SqlDataReader contains one or more rows.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using [FieldCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.fieldcount(v=vs.110).aspx)
, use [HasRows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.hasrows(v=vs.110).aspx).

`FieldCount` Will only return the number or columns in current row Instead of number of rows in current table.

For Example:

```
if(db.HasRows)
{
    result.Read();
    model = new Model.Customer()
    {
          Username = result.GetString(0),
          Password = result.GetString(1)
    };                    
}
else
{
    model = null;
}
```